# What do $x\in (1,5)$ and $x\in [1,5]$ mean?

Tags: notation

Simple question, is there any difference between $x\in (1,5)$, $x\in [1,5]$ and $x\in (1,5]$? and what is the value of $x$ in those cases?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what interval notation is? Each of those means a different sort of set.

Comment: Do you think $1\in (1,5)$? How about $1\in [1,5]$?

Comment: "*What is the value of $x$ in each of those cases?*"  It is unspecified beyond what has already been said with the statement in question.  $x\in[1,5]$ means that $x$ is a real number such that it is greater than or equal to $1$ and less than or equal to $5$.  The statement would be true in the case that $x=2$ for instance, and would also be true in the case that $x=\pi$ or $x=4.7$ or even $x=5$ among infinitely many other possible scenarios.

Comment: A set such as $(1,5)$ which does not contain its boundary points is also called *open*; a set such as $[1,5]$ which does is called *closed*. There is a good reason why the distinct notations exist: how would you denote the set $(1,5)$ using square brackets? $[1.01,4.99]$? $[1.000001, 4.999999]$? You can see how no such way of describing the set that starts "just after 1" and ends "just before 5" using square brackets would be adequate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have
$$[1,5] = \{ x\in \mathbb R \mid 1 \leq x \leq 5 \},$$
$$(1,5) = \{ x\in \mathbb R \mid 1 < x < 5 \},$$
$$(1,5] = \{ x\in \mathbb R \mid 1 < x \leq 5 \},$$
so they all are sets that include all real numbers strictly between $1$ and $5$, but the first one also contains both $1$ and $5$, the second contains neither $1$ nor $5$ and the third one contains $5$, but not $1$.

When we write $x\in [1,5]$, we don't assign a particular value to $x$, we just say that $x$ is a real number such that $1 \leq x \leq 5$, and similarly for the others.